# Discord.py currency system earn random money

Tags: python, discord.py

So im trying to make an economy bot where the user can register first in order to make an account so they can be a part of the economy system, and now im trying to make the earn money command by letting the bot give random earning to the user who send the command with a 5 minutes cooldown and then im experiencing an error where the earn money command didnt work as expected, heres the full code, the problem was on the (getprimo) one :

```html
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def wallet(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id in amounts:
        em1 = discord.Embed(title = f'Wallet', description = "You have {} <:primogem:853895082646044672> in paimon bank <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.".format(amounts[id]), color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em1)
    else:
        em2 = discord.Embed(title = f'Account Not Registered', description = f'You do not have an account <:_pBaffled:827075083670650950>.\nUse %register to make an account.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em2)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        em3 = discord.Embed(title = f'Account Successfully Registered', description = f'You are now registered  <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em3)
        _save()
    else:
        em4 = discord.Embed(title = f'Account Already Registered', description = f'You already have an account <:_pBaffled:827075083670650950>.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em4)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx, other: discord.Member, amount: int):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        em5 = discord.Embed(title = f'Account Not Registered', description = f'You do not have an account <:_pBaffled:827075083670650950>.\nUse %register to make an account.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em5)
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        em6 = discord.Embed(title = f'Account Not Registered', description = f'You cant send <:primogem:853895082646044672> to someone that does not have an account.\nTell the person to use %register first in order to send the <:primogem:853895082646044672>.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em6)
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        em7 = discord.Embed(title = f'Not Enough Primogems', description = f'Insufficient <:primogem:853895082646044672>.\nCant send <:primogem:853895082646044672> to {other.mention} <:_pHug:827086739435683840>.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em7)
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        em8 = discord.Embed(title = f'Send Successful', description = f'Done sending {amount} <:primogem:853895082646044672> to {other.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.', color= ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em8)
        _save()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def getprimo(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    amount = random.randrange(0, 100)
    amounts[id] += amount
    em9 = discord.Embed(title = f'Primogems Earned', description = f'You get {amount} <:primogem:853895082646044672>.\nPlease wait 5 minutes to get more primo <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.', color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = em9)
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@client.command()
async def save():
    _save()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you provide your full traceback to the code you were having trouble with? It will help us help you better 

Comment: @Bagle theres no error traceback in my terminal when im typing the command, its just empty and didnt work.

Comment: do you have an error handler somewhere? if so, comment it out for now and see if there is an error

Comment: No error message, for the other command is just fine and the bot goes online with its login notif on my terminal when the bot turned on and when i type the getprimo command there, the command didnt work, the command supposedly to give a random amount of money to the user and then its just nothing happened. and also no error msg in my terminal and my bot still run perfectly for another command.  Well thats the error ive been experiencing for this one.

Comment: I dont know how to fix this error stuff, either my function is wrong or im lacking of some function and definition there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally found out the answer, sorry for asking this before. If you want to know, here's the fixed code for what problem I got before. I changed the "amount" and the "id" there because it's just a test before.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def getprimo(ctx):
    primaryid = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    earning = random.randint(0, 100)
    amounts[primaryid] += earning
    em9 = discord.Embed(title = f'Primogems Earned', description = f'You get {earning} <:primogem:853895082646044672>.\nPlease wait 5 minutes to get more primo <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.', color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = em9)
    _save()
```

Instead of `random.randint`, I'm using `random.randrange` before and that's the reason why the command didn't work.